# Confused about this php code using curly braces

Tags: php, curly-braces

```
while ( is_numeric( $flyer{$idPos} )) {
    //some code
}
```

What does `$flyer{$idPos}` mean assuming both are variables?

Comment: @BenM This is not within a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an alternative, not recommendable syntax for accessing array entries:

```
$flyer{$idPos} === $flyer[$idPos]
```

Comment: @Aditya then please mark this answer as the correct answer by clicking on the green bordered tick on the left

Comment: @bwoebi The syntax is actually documented. http://php.net/array has a small "Note" on it :)

Comment: @NikiC It took me now about 5 minutes to find it… Thanks for the hint :o (Didn't find it before)

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are a way to access a specific character of a string

```
$str = 'Bob';
echo $str{0}; // outputs B
```

Comment: Like bwoebi says it's a different way to access arrays, same as [] and a string can be accessed like an array of chars. [] are anyways better as they cause less confusion:)